# Download Zanox product feed to server

Tags: php, xml, curl, download

After two days of struggling my last hopes are on you.
I'm trying to download a large (+/- 160 mb) XML-file from the Zanox servers. 
The download link to this file is dynamic and does not directly point to the file itself.
I'm trying to download this file to my own server to parse it, but it's not working out for me. 
I've been using curl with the `CURLOPT_HEADER` set to `0`.
Can you guys help me out maybe?

Regards.

One of the codes I used:

```
$fp = fopen("productfeed1.xml", 'w+');
$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
$contents = curl_exec($c);
$info = curl_getinfo($c);
fwrite($fp, $contents);
curl_close($c); 
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: We cannot help of you do not post your code so far, explain what exactly the issue is and allow us to help you.

Comment: I added one of the codes I have used, the issue is that I'm trying to download a file from a dynamic url, but the standard approach doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a helpful description. What does that mean? What happens if you do it? Nothing happens? Do you get some error or some unexpected result? Does the universe implode?

Comment: A wild guess, since you don't say what result you get: maybe you are missing the `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` flag?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get an error, I just get a blank page. 
@arkascha; still no response with that flag added.

Comment: A blank page? Ok, that is valuable information. Next question: what appears in the http servers log files? That is where php outputs errors...

Comment: Oh, didn't know that! The server gives this error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Ok, we are a step further! 1. I checked the code (with the additional flag) and I have no problems downloading a file with it, so the code is fine. 2. the error you get is a server side error. If that page (I don't know that page) works fine otherwise then most likely you use their API in a way they did not expect. I suggest you  contact them and ask why their API crashes.

Comment: Well that's the problem, I'm not using an API, that's not necessary..

Comment: Since you do not tell us the url or what you mean by "dynamic" there is little else I can do for you...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give you the URL. And what I mean by 'dynamic' is that the file is generated on the remote server.

Comment: It is irrelevant if that file is static or gets generated dynamically on-the-fly. How do you know that the file can be generated and downloaded _at all_? Do you succeed by an interactive browser session? Then most likely both requests simply differ. You have to find out where they differ. Easiest for this is to dump both network conversations and take a close look at things like http headers, hidden input fields and cookie values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. (It works for me)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 36000);
curl_exec($ch);
```